# Unexpected parse error T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, sql

I am encountering the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in H:\STUDENT\S0213628\part2\friendslist.php on line 7

With the following sql command:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT ubuser.usr_firstname, ubuser.usr_lastname, ubuser.usr_DOB,  
ubuser2_1.usr_firstname & " " & ubuser2_1.usr_lastname AS UBFriend,
ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1, ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2, ubuser.usr_ID, ubuser2_1.usr_ID 
FROM ubuser AS ubuser2_1 INNER JOIN (ubFriendsLink INNER JOIN ubuser 
ON ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1 = ubuser.usr_ID) ON ubuser2_1.usr_ID = 
ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2 WHERE (((ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1) = ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] .")) 
OR (((ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2) = ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] ."))";
```

The command is designed to show updates from both the user with the session ID and any friends linked to that user via the friends link table (either using ID1 or ID2).

The command seems to work in access, yet does not work when i incorporate the sql into my php page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `& " " & ` - double quotes inside double quotes need escaping... and you're possibly better using the SQL CONCAT() function `CONCAT(ubuser2_1.usr_firstname, ' ', ubuser2_1.usr_lastname) as UBFriend` - depending on your flavour of database

Comment: Or in other words, change that part to `& \" \" &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `& "` you're closing your starting quote. You need to escape it with a backslash:

```
$sql = 
"SELECT ubuser.usr_firstname, ubuser.usr_lastname, ubuser.usr_DOB,  
ubuser2_1.usr_firstname & \" \" & ubuser2_1.usr_lastname AS UBFriend,
ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1, ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2, ubuser.usr_ID, ubuser2_1.usr_ID 
FROM ubuser AS ubuser2_1 INNER JOIN (ubFriendsLink INNER JOIN ubuser 
ON ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1 = ubuser.usr_ID) ON ubuser2_1.usr_ID = 
ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2 WHERE (((ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1) = ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] .")) 
OR (((ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2) = ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] ."))";
```

Answer (score 0):

double quotes inside double quotes are causing issue.

```
$sql = 
"SELECT ubuser.usr_firstname, ubuser.usr_lastname, ubuser.usr_DOB,  
ubuser2_1.usr_firstname & \" \" & ubuser2_1.usr_lastname AS UBFriend,
ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1, ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2, ubuser.usr_ID, ubuser2_1.usr_ID 
FROM ubuser AS ubuser2_1 INNER JOIN (ubFriendsLink INNER JOIN ubuser 
ON ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1 = ubuser.usr_ID) ON ubuser2_1.usr_ID = 
ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2 WHERE (((ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID1) = ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] .")) 
OR (((ubFriendsLink.ub_lnkID2) = ".$_SESSION['usr_ID'] ."))
```